# How should I treat GENDER factor when exploring the relationships between two given variables?

Tags: r, regression, lm

The following data frame `df` contains observations on two different measures of muscle strength (`VAR_1` and `VAR_2`) from 24 males and 16 females. Both variables present a fairly linear relationship:

```
library("ggplot2")

ggplot(df, aes(x = VAR_1, y = VAR_2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = "black")
```

[image]

However, a closer look at GENDER reveals that Females are mainly locaten in the lower left part of the plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = VAR_1, y = VAR_2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = GENDER)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = "black") + 
  geom_smooth(aes(color = GENDER), method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

The fact that females present lower outcomes in both variables affects modeling predictions including the entire dataset or only data from one gender. However, although women are usually weaker than men, there is no rationale to think that the relationship between both `VAR_1` and `VAR_2` is gender dependent.

Are there any "best practices" when it comes to fairly evaluating and interpreting the relationship between these two variables, accounting for any potential effect of GENDER?

Here we have some linear regressions including the entire data set:

```
fit <- lm(VAR_2 ~ VAR_1, data = df)
summary(fit)
```

Which results in:

```
> summary(fit)
Call:
lm(formula = VAR_2 ~ VAR_1, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-250.35 -114.86  -39.01  111.72  388.73 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 406.87642  104.55822   3.891 0.000389 ***
VAR_1         0.46927    0.06506   7.212 1.27e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 164.3 on 38 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5779,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5668 
F-statistic: 52.02 on 1 and 38 DF,  p-value: 1.271e-08
```

Or accounting for GENDER in the linear regression call:

```
fit_gender <- lm(VAR_2 ~ VAR_1 + GENDER, data = df)
summary(fit_gender)
```

Which gives:

```
> summary(fit_gender)

Call:
lm(formula = VAR_2 ~ VAR_1 + GENDER, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-284.07 -113.23  -43.72  104.85  262.45 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   804.85032  176.94587   4.549 5.64e-05 ***
VAR_1           0.26776    0.09621   2.783  0.00843 ** 
GENDERFemale -210.73340   78.39083  -2.688  0.01070 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 152.3 on 37 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6468,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6278 
F-statistic: 33.88 on 2 and 37 DF,  p-value: 4.339e-09
```

Data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(GENDER = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("Male", "Female"), class = "factor"), VAR_1 = c(2032.95602228266, 
1645.84136319679, 1795.26082107151, 1547.11851437409, 1473.71473099518, 
1654.41457933987, 2085.89855247696, 1840.30988797414, 1731.83124703822, 
1892.49168271771, 1659.2423200817, 2379.84411458054, 1342.45455728821, 
1309.87878136455, 1787.29982936431, 2147.67880389956, 1663.31028977522, 
1982.42647407018, 1982.39817891865, 2454.85027809758, 1876.8911269728, 
1788.31575689296, 1807.61528947627, 1571.47753963486, 962.514829411152, 
1182.58776863074, 1424.9201681673, 1214.0785590926, 1334.2561628931, 
1406.04081361931, 918.426537504858, 1321.03726255393, 1112.46568701098, 
1082.76212547093, 1157.27133152872, 1003.82141604491, 761.377814135862, 
1357.58749106345, 1067.86384075784, 1504.80678366675), VAR_2 = c(1495.11161840391, 
1171.28580423435, 1517.91576982039, 1160.83516847309, 1290.3390955332, 
1441.8949803003, 1174.30294841121, 1150.19303667107, 1427.70217475294, 
1142.25248430695, 1510.12367036879, 1464.08394200785, 1243.4746868308, 
1410.30146350545, 1175.79442393805, 1452.33610135076, 1139.05191957201, 
1125.09462604151, 1271.39561360677, 1724.61669651112, 1255.6498053177, 
1126.06937977549, 1004.78747531315, 1076.94960273115, 948.981977327285, 
994.937522527885, 1016.5226800106, 883.513636610965, 871.08484388274, 
1177.64099985273, 765.812857284995, 807.463314572285, 906.32646936372, 
744.15494510974, 1031.9543118962, 764.79678843817, 725.83893532882, 
1157.98504077507, 868.308441582335, 877.61788082039)), .Names = c("GENDER", 
"VAR_1", "VAR_2"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Have you tried having two regressions, one for men, one for women?  Then compare the range of the coefficients to see if there is overlap?

Comment: @user38826 yes, I have tried that, and there is overlap. However, I am not sure how that information will affect my choice of presenting gender-specific vs. all data set linear regression results.

Comment: my thinking was if the coefficients are likely similar and there is no heteroskedasticity and intuition tells you they are similar then treat them as one model for the sake of minimizing the amount of extrapolation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*However, although women are usually weaker than men, there is no rationale to think that the relationship between both VAR_1 and VAR_2 is gender dependent.*"

I assume you mean that there is no *a priori* reason to expect that the slope between the two genders is different, even though your plots suggest that this might be the case.

You could simply test for an interaction between VAR_1 and GENDER while trying to explain VAR_2 in a linear model. In fact, you could construct a set of nested models and compare them with your preferred method (I'll use AIC here):

```
fit1 <- lm(VAR_2 ~ 1, data = df)
fit2 <- lm(VAR_2 ~ VAR_1, data = df)
fit3 <- lm(VAR_2 ~ GENDER, data = df)
fit4 <- lm(VAR_2 ~ VAR_1 + GENDER, data = df)
fit5 <- lm(VAR_2 ~ VAR_1 * GENDER, data = df)

AIC(fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4, fit5)
```

This should tell you which terms are important to consider.

Your example is related to an interesting phenomenon known as [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox).

Comment: How should AIC values be used to detect significantly different slopes (i.e. is there any threshold)? In the example above, similar AIC values are obtained (520.44 and 521.85 for the `fit_gender1` and `fit_gender2` models, respectively). 
Thanks

Comment: @AJMA Like p-values, there are commonly used thresholds for the difference in AIC between models (called delta AIC), but one should be careful about their interpretation. The thresholds seem to differ by field - 2 in some, 7 in others, and I've also heard of 10. But if you're unfamiliar with AIC, you could as easily perform an ANOVA to compare the two models. In your case, you have the slightly annoying situation where the models are essentially equivalent. In this case, I would be inclined to present the model with the interaction while acknowledging that the evidence for it is weak.

Comment: Thanks @mkt, I may compare them using `anova.lm{stats}`. However, I wonder why you propose to compare two models, both comprising GENDER  but using `+` or `*`, respectively. Would it be reasonable to compare two different models, performed only on males or females, respectively?

Comment: @AJMA I was making the (unjustified) assumption that the only relevant comparison was between a model with or without an interaction; obviously, it's entirely possible that the gender difference doesn't matter. I will edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I've now added a complete set of models (assuming only linear relationships and simple interactions). Again, I've compared them with AIC, but you could do a series of ANOVA comparisons instead.

Comment: And to answer your question directly: I do not see the point in analysing males & females separately; you are already accounting for possible differences in the models shown above.